# We can't make bootable macOS Mavericks bootable USB flash drives anymore?

Tags: macos, bootable-media, osx-mavericks

I've been using macOS Mavericks (10.9.5) for years and have done quite a few times of re-installing using bootable USB flash drive, made by using the terminal commands. However today I tried to create a bootable USB flash drive for Mavericks once again, but it keeps saying "couldn't mount InstallESD.dmg", then I found out the main reason is this dmg file is not mountable anymore.

I tried the methods provided by [@startergo in their answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454243/485968), it is because that `.dmg` file is actually an XAR file, then I followed his steps and finally managed to create a bootable USB flash drive, however when I tried to actually install the system, it shows "the copy can't be verified".

Now I'm pretty sure the Mavericks app I downloaded from Mac App store in 2023 is different from what I got in the previous years, and the `installESD.dmg` is the major problem.

Does anyone have a good, working solution to this?

Comment: What does Mavericks have that is lost in El Capitan? Your actual issue aside, it seems a funny place to stop. Also, what OS are you using to create the USB?

Comment: Also… Mavericks seems to be singularly unloved in the current macOS installer list - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211683 All the other installers have been tweaked over the past couple of years to avoid the out of date certificate issues that plagued the older ones [you used to have to set the date on your computer to the year each was released for it to work]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I have noticed that Mavericks was the forgotten one in the current installer list which is pretty interesting, maybe they found some known issues of this version and decided to not allow people use it any more, just like iOS 9 couldn't be activated today any more. I also tried to set the date when installing, but still no luck, maybe it's because the installer files were modified by myself, but without the modifications I couldn't even get a bootable USB driver.

Comment: I need Mavericks for some old apps and functions. I don't really want to download another installer from a random website, so like you said it is a good reason to switch to a later version which is still supported by my Macbook, EI Capitan would be a good one. I've been trying this for 2 nights and I feel like there's something beyond our ability which stopped us from re-installing Mavericks. Hope more people will notice this matter and a solution can eventually come out.

Comment: I very much doubt Apple will make any further changes to the current structure for old OSes. They did recently re-jig them all [except apparently Mavericks] after an issue where *all* the certificates went bad, but I wouldn't expect them to make any more changes. Anything older than Catalina is obsolete.

Comment: Not sure whether you're still monitoring this QA, but have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275 which has been updated a lot recently, especially the links to `maclinks.publicvm.com` which is maintained by one of our high rep users & contains links & USB build instructions for old OSes right back to Snow Leo, including Mavericks. I've tested many of these recently… though not actually Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a USB, which will bypass all the certificates crap:

```
pkgutil --expand /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg ~/Mavericks
cd ~/Mavericks/InstallMacOSX.pkg && hdiutil attach InstallESD.dmg
cd /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD && cp BaseSystem.dmg ~/Mavericks/
asr imagescan --source ~/Mavericks/BaseSystem.dmg
```

- Find your USB device and the Apple_HFS partition on it:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk19 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk19
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk19s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                7.7 GB     disk19s2
```

```
sudo asr restore --source ~/Mavericks/BaseSystem.dmg --target /dev/disk19s2 --erase
rm /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/Packages
cp -R /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/Packages  /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation
cp -R /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/BaseSystem.dmg  /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System
cp /Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/BaseSystem.chunklist  /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System
```